# A controller before_filter has no effect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In Rails 4, I use `before_action :require_login` for my `UserController`. This is supposed to redirect if the user is not logged in. However the filter doesn't seem to be used. Why?

`require_login` is defined in `app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb`. So it is not a helper for my controller UsersController.

How does `UserController` know to use the function from `sessions_helper.rb`? It seems like I should be more specific: `before_action "session/require_login"`.

The controller in users_controller.rb:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :signed_in_user

  def index
  end
end
```

The helper function in sessions_helper.rb:

```
  def require_login
    unless signed_in?
      store_location
      redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in." unless signed_in?
    end
  end
```

Comment: Put a raise or something in it, to see if it is getting called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're following Michael Hartl's tutorial? Helpers in /app/helpers designed for view logic, not for controller code.

However, to get the helper included into your controllers you can use `include SessionsHelper`.

Reference: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#code-sessions_helper_include

Answer (score 1):

`before_filter` can only call controller method, not helper.

You need to move the helper `require_login` from helper to UsesController or its parent say ApplicationController.

If you still want to use `require_login` as a helper in view, you can expose it from controller by `helper_method`

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_fitler :require_login
  helper_method :require_login

  def require_login
    # code
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks @Billy - I added "include SessionsHelper" in my ApplicationControllers, but it's still not having an effect

Comment: The logic in that method is pure controller, why you want to define it as a helper but not controller method? You can always expose controller method to helper but not vice versa.